# Multiple (cascade) equal operator in TSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I could not guess the true term (multiple equality operator or else) but sample is here:

```
UPDATE Account  
SET @newOverall = Overall = Overall - @Amount   
FROM Account WHERE Id = @accountId
```

@newOverall **=** Overall **=** Overall - @Amount

Is it convenient for TSql (on Microsoft Sql Server)

**EDIT**

Both answers seem correct. (Thanks Vladimir and M.Ali) If your table contains Trigger and you need to get scalar value then Vladimir's way is better(safer). If your update affects multiple records and you need to get all of the changed records than M.Ali's way is winner. But I had to choose M.Ali's way because I think OUTPUT was created for this situations and it is more generic solution. Thanks for test code Vladimir. (Stackoverflow we need Multiple Accepted Answer! :))

Comment: What is the purpose of this operation/idiom?

Comment: What do you mean by "convenient for TSql"?

Comment: That syntax is acceptable but can be confusing,

Comment: I will use @newOverall after this operation (I will insert it to Transaction table) INSERT INTO [Transaction] VALUES (@date,@accountId,@Amount,@newOverall)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**KISS**(keep it simple Sugar) you can make use of OUTPUT clause in your UPDATE statement do something like this....

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE(Overall INT)

UPDATE Account  
SET Overall = Overall - @Amount  
OUTPUT inserted.Overall INTO @TABLE(Overall) 
WHERE Id = @accountId
```

Your Insert statement will be something like

```
INSERT INTO [Transaction] 
SELECT @date,@accountId,@Amount,Overall
FROM @Table
```

Answer (score 2):

Syntax that you specified is perfectly valid and will work just fine, but to avoid confusion I would modify it to this.

```
UPDATE Account
    SET Overall = Overall - @Amount
       ,@newOverall = Overall - @Amount
    FROM Account
    WHERE Id = @accountId
```

Note that `@newOverall` variable will only reflect last assigned value. In cases if you have updated more than 1 row this will cause you a problem.

Here is a test, both methods return same results.

```
DECLARE @newOverall INT
   ,@Amount INT = 1;

DECLARE @Account TABLE ( Overall INT )

INSERT INTO @Account
    VALUES  ( 10 ),
            ( 15 ),
            ( 13 )

UPDATE @Account
    SET Overall = Overall - @Amount
       ,@newOverall = Overall - @Amount
    FROM @Account

SELECT *
    FROM @Account;
SELECT @newOverall

DELETE FROM @Account

INSERT INTO @Account
    VALUES  ( 10 ),
            ( 15 ),
            ( 13 );

UPDATE @Account
    SET @newOverall = Overall = Overall - @Amount
    FROM @Account

SELECT *
    FROM @Account;
SELECT @newOverall;
```

Comment: I've edited question with detailed explanation. Writing test code also admiring attitude.Thanks Vladimir.